# Get the x,y inside a circle

Tags: c

I'm using the algorithms (circle and ellipse) available at this page: http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html

However, these just calculate the outside of the circle. How can I determine which x,y are inside the circle?

The **Circle** algorithm is this:

```
void plotCircle(int xm, int ym, int r)
{
   int x = -r, y = 0, err = 2-2*r; /* II. Quadrant */ 
   do {
      setPixel(xm-x, ym+y); /*   I. Quadrant */
      setPixel(xm-y, ym-x); /*  II. Quadrant */
      setPixel(xm+x, ym-y); /* III. Quadrant */
      setPixel(xm+y, ym+x); /*  IV. Quadrant */
      r = err;
      if (r <= y) err += ++y*2+1;           /* e_xy+e_y < 0 */
      if (r > x || err > y) err += ++x*2+1; /* e_xy+e_x > 0 or no 2nd y-step */
   } while (x < 0);
}
```

The **Ellipse** algorithm is this:

```
void plotEllipseRect(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
   int a = abs(x1-x0), b = abs(y1-y0), b1 = b&1; /* values of diameter */
   long dx = 4*(1-a)*b*b, dy = 4*(b1+1)*a*a; /* error increment */
   long err = dx+dy+b1*a*a, e2; /* error of 1.step */

   if (x0 > x1) { x0 = x1; x1 += a; } /* if called with swapped points */
   if (y0 > y1) y0 = y1; /* .. exchange them */
   y0 += (b+1)/2; y1 = y0-b1;   /* starting pixel */
   a *= 8*a; b1 = 8*b*b;

   do {
       setPixel(x1, y0); /*   I. Quadrant */
       setPixel(x0, y0); /*  II. Quadrant */
       setPixel(x0, y1); /* III. Quadrant */
       setPixel(x1, y1); /*  IV. Quadrant */
       e2 = 2*err;
       if (e2 <= dy) { y0++; y1--; err += dy += a; }  /* y step */ 
       if (e2 >= dx || 2*err > dy) { x0++; x1--; err += dx += b1; } /* x step */
   } while (x0 <= x1);

   while (y0-y1 < b) {  /* too early stop of flat ellipses a=1 */
       setPixel(x0-1, y0); /* -> finish tip of ellipse */
       setPixel(x1+1, y0++); 
       setPixel(x0-1, y1);
       setPixel(x1+1, y1--); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you simply asking how to determine if a point is within a circle? Do you have the center and radius?

Comment: On the circle algorithm it uses a center and radius. On the ellipse it uses a rectangle (start/stop points)

Comment: That site is blocked for me (an opendns security warning), can  you post some of the information here?

Comment: This seems more like a math question than a coding question.

Comment: @juharr I cannot read mathematical notation. And I'm coding... There are many other questions like this, others I've posted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the centre of the circle is at x0, y0 and the radius is r then the point x, y is in or on the edge of the circle if and only if (x - x0)(x - x0) + (y - y0)(y - y0) is less than or equal to the square of r.

You can implement this in c and c# very simply.